# Calculate a transaction version 2 ID

Tags: transactions, transaction-id

Been writing a bitcoin library from scratch, which eventually involves calculating transaction IDs.

Version 1 transactions work fine when their hex data is being SHA256'd twice and then reversed.

Version 2 transactions ids don't seem to work that way, according to data I found on block explorers. The IDs I generate never match.

Why?

Comment: The algorithm for computing txids is the same for version 1 and version 2. But is it possible that the v2 transactions you're looking at are segwit transactions? Because those do have a different hashing algorithm, see BIP141 and BIP144.

Comment: Take any V1 transaction in mempool.space, click `Transaction hex`, and then double-sha256 what you get, then reverse it... matches the ID in the URL. The same doesn't seem to apply for any v2 transaction... no idea why.

Comment: Recent transactions are likely segwit transactions. For those you need to drop the witness before hashing to obtain the txid. It has nothing to do with v1 or v2 however; either can be segwit or not.

Comment: Invaluable information, Pieter... thank you so much! Will take a good look a that.

Comment: Sure does, @RedGrittyBrick !